# SonarQube multiple type of tests

Tags: c#, sonarqube, nunit, mstest

In my project i use two type of tests : nunit and mstest.
In my build server for project i had build step :

```
"%SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe%" begin /k:"%sonar.proj.key%" /n:"%sonar.proj.name%" /v:"%sonar.proj.version%" /d:sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths="NUnitResults.xml"  /d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths="MSTestResults.trx"
```

But always i have metrics by mstests, in build log i dont see anything about parsing NUnitResults by sonarqube. Question: sonarqube supports parsing and analyse two type of tests ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "You can import reports from different tools by passing several
> /d:propertyKey="path" arguments (with different property keys) to the
> MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin command"

From [Unit Test Execution Results Import (C#, VB.NET)](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389772)

Out of interest, are you using two different test frameworks in the same MSBuild project, or in different frameworks in different MSBuild projects?